# Spring Boot - Remove external "/error" endpoint access

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, error-handling

### Introduction

I have a custom `ErrorController` implementation to handle all exceptions and create a custom error message:

```
@RestController
public class CustomErrorController implements ErrorController {
    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public ResponseEntity handleError(HttpServletRequest request) {
        HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.valueOf((Integer) request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_STATUS_CODE));
        String body = ... // Code to calculate the body based on the request
        return ResponseEntity.status(status.value()).body(body);
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return "/error";
    }
}
```

### Problem Description

However, this also enables access to the path `/error` which I would like to disable.

When trying to access `https://localhost:8443/error`, a `NullPointerException` is thrown by the `HttpStatus.valueOf()` method, because the status code could not be extracted. As a result, an Internal Server Error (500) is created, which is run through my custom controller, creating a custom 500 error response.

### Temporary Fix

As a workaround, I can check if the status code attribute exists, and handle that case separately. But it is a work-around and not an actual *fix*.

### The Question

**What I would like is to disable the `/error` mapping from external access. If attempted, the result should be Not Found (404) which is then run through my custom controller.**

Is the `@RequestMapping("/error")` necessary or could this be implemented differently?

### Edits

1. Spring Boot version is `2.1.2.RELEASE`
2. The `server.error.whitelabel.enabled` property is set to `false`. The issue does not seem to be related with it.

Comment: Which version spring boot?

Comment: Spring Boot `2.1.2.RELEASE`